# Web3 and Metamask interaction doesn't work

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have my Metamask open connected to the Rinkeby network.

In Andreas' Mastering Ethereum book he has the following instructions to interact with Web3.

"Open a Javascript Console in a Broswer with Metamask running... and then type web3.eth.getTransactionCount('0xF962e09a92F4127bbC770c22aF41a0c3BaF0b66a')"

Why is this not working for me?  Thank you

[image]

Comment: The error-message `web3 is not defined` tells you exactly what the problem is. Do you import `web3` anywhere???

Comment: I didn't import Web3 on my machine.  There was no mention of this step in the book unless I missed it.  I thought Web3 was installed as part of the Metamask extension.

Comment: I'd like to install as little as possible on my machine.  I use remix currently to compile my solidity code.  Do I need to install NodeJs to get access to Web3?  Thank you.  https://medium.com/b2expand/install-web3-fc96b885a7b

Comment: I watched some videos on YouTube in regards to Web3.  It appears I need to install Node.js.  I will hold off on doing this right now.

Comment: @Picard78 Metamask has been deprecating web3 for some time, it seems in the last release they have removed it enterely. The book as a github repo, perhaps you can ask there if there's an update to that part of the book https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook.

Comment: On the Github version they changed Metamask to Geth.  "Open a JavaScript console in Geth (or your preferred web3 interface)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned that I can interact with web3 from the Remix Terminal.  As Ismael stated web3 has been deprecated from Metamask.  Note: for this to work with Rinkeby, a connection must be made via Injected Web3 to Metamask from Remix.

[image]